# Interface vs. Abstract class for a model with objects that share some attributes

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface, abstract-class

My application is mainly composed of **Campaigns**. They are the main object of my model.
I have two types of campaign:

1. **Ad hoc**: Campaigns that are run once immediately
2. **Scheduled**: Campaigns that are scheduled for future and can be run multiple times according to their schedule.

There are shared attributes between these two and there are attributes that are specific to each. What is the best way to design this data model? `Interfaces` or `Abstract classes`?

Let's say both types of campaigns can have an *Id* and a *Name* and:

- Only Ad hoc campaigns have a `DataTable` called *Recipients*
- Only Scheduled campaigns have a `List<DateTime>` called *Schedule*

If you're kind enough not to vote me down or ask to close this question, please provide a basic structure of your recommended model including `access modifiers` and the `abstract/virtual` or another keyword that will help me have a better structure for my model.

Comment: *please provide a basic structure of your recommended model including access modifiers and the abstract/virtual or another keyword that will help me have a better structure for my model.* - You want someone to design your entire architecture for you? Best post your whole spec then.

Comment: Voting down is not an act of meanness. And sadly your question seems to me to be opinion based. But I'll let people do their own, opinion.

Comment: Use an abstract class if you need to implement any common routines, properties etc... You can also use an interface and then have an abstract class implement that interface.

Comment: @AntP No I don't want anyone to design my entire architecture. I'm just looking for the best way to handle this design.

Comment: Okay, I was exaggerating slightly, but I was trying to stress the point that nobody can answer this question given the provided information. There is absolutely nothing in the question that suggests that abstract classes or interfaces would be more appropriate - the information is far too high-level. At any rate, the answer is probably "a combination of both." If you have shared functionality, use abstract base classes. If not, don't. You're probably going to want to use interfaces anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is very difficult to answer without a very good understanding of what you're doing and it is unfortunately very opinion based.

However at a very simple level if you use an interface you will often have to duplicate code between the implementing properties (methods, properties and so on). A base class provides this functionality to them. For this reason I often use a base class unless there's a specific reason why an interface is more appropriate.

I would suggest different types of campaigns are all campaigns in essence and so have a base class. However they will target different entities (people, charities, companies) which will all need a way of contacting them (email/phone/address) I'd suggest that these unrelated entities (beyond the fact they can be targeted by a campaign) are a better example of when to use an interface.

However you will need to think about which methods you would override and which is the cleaner solution.

Comment: I agree. FOr example. I fail to see any difference except a marker (ad hoc, scheduled) and would handle both from ONE model, so tha scheduled campcaigns also CAN have recipients.... and ad hoc either has zero schedule or gets the current moment as schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if they share common *behavior* (code), that code should exist in an abstract class. If they perform the same *role*, put them behind an interface.

In your case you seem to have two shared properties, both a simple value, which does not really define behavior, so just based on those properties I'd go for just an interface.

If you do decide to create an abstract class (perhaps there is some code both types would like to share), you could still keep the interface. You could some day have a third campaign type that does not share behavior with the other ones (so does not implement the same abstract class), but does perform the same role (so does implement the same interface).

As for access modifiers in an abstract class, if both classes share only two properties, you just define them in the abstract class without `abstract` or `virtual` keyword.

Comment: I think a major question is where the BLL is too. Is it campaign.Send() or Send(campaign)?